# Issue with Table_Date_Range function

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my below query, when i run it, it seems to ask me to add a group by to a record that is not in my statement.

```
SELECT date, 
SUM(totals.visits) as visits,
SUM(totals.transactions) as Transactions,
SUM( totals.transactionRevenue) as Revenue,
SUM (hits.eCommerceAction.action_type ='3'),
Sites
FROM 
(SELECT *, "SiteA" as Sites
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([mydata.ga_sessions_],DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -6, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY'))), 
(TABLE_DATE_RANGE([mydata.ga_sessions_intraday_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()))
GROUP BY
date
ORDER BY
date DESC);
```

please let me know
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wrongly positioned your group by and order by.
Assuming that the rest of code make sense - Below should work

```
SELECT 
  date, 
  SUM(totals.visits) AS visits,
  SUM(totals.transactions) AS Transactions,
  SUM( totals.transactionRevenue) AS Revenue,
  SUM (hits.eCommerceAction.action_type ='3'),
  Sites
FROM (
  SELECT *, "SiteA" AS Sites
  FROM 
  (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([mydata.ga_sessions_],DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -6, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY'))), 
  (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([mydata.ga_sessions_intraday_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()))
)
GROUP BY date, Sites
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: thanks. i have voted it. Do you know which metrics we should use in Bigquery to get data on goals?

Comment: I would recommend you to check https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719. If you have more questions - I suggest posting new question as this gives you more chances for answer for it. And if it is google-analytics related - you better also to add respective tag to your new question :o)